# Moivre y sus Raices, No entiendo que poner en n.

Tags: measure-theory

Ejercicio --> $(-1+i)^1/3$

No me dice a que raiz tengo que pasarlo.

formula -->  $wk = z^1/n = p^1/n[\cos(θ+2kπ/n) + i \sin(θ+2kπ/n)]$

No se si $n=3$ o $n=1/3$. claramente wk iria sumando hasta el 3 si es que es $n=3$ no?

Alguno sabe que tengo que poner en n? Gracias.

Comment: n=3____________